# Encryption in php and AES decryption in angular using crypto JS

Tags: php, angular, aes, cryptojs

This is my below encryption & decryption in PHP and it working fine, But I need to decrypt the same thing in angular 7 ,

```
Encryption in php using aes-256-cbc by following method
$this->data ="plaintext";
$this->
openssl_encrypt("plaintext", "aes-256-cbc", "1234567890",0,"1234567890")
```

But I tried with crypto-js but it return the empty value,

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("ciphertext","1234567890".toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

suggest any idea to do that.

My objective is encrypt the string in php and decrypt the value in angular

Comment: You have completely wrong syntax of code: 2 opening bracket and closing only one.

Comment: I have put the example , it didn't matter

Comment: In your PHP code you're using the wrong key- and IV-size.

Comment: Topaco, But it decrypt in php

Comment: You should see a warning concerning the IV (unless warnings are disabled in your environment). AES uses a 16 bytes IV and the variant AES-256 needs a 32 bytes key. If the values are shorter, PHP implicitly pads with 0x00 values. If you replace your IV with e.g. `1234567890\0\0\0\0\0\0`, you will get the same result.

Comment: AS per your suggesssion, I tried with IV as 1234567890123456 but it working in php not in cryptoJs

Comment: I got the wordArray object as response from cryptoJs decryption

Comment: You must pass key and IV as `WordArray`: `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, keyWA, {iv: ivWA});`. `WordArray`s can be created with encoders e.g.: `var ivWA = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("1234567890123456");`
If you then use the _same_ keys and IVs in _both_ codes, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
const configuration = {
  keySize: 128 / 8,
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('<your initialization vector>'),
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
};

CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("ciphertext", "<your encryption key>", configuration).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Gopal Zadafiya , I got wordArray object after CryptoJS.AES.decrypt , so i need solution for converting the wordArray to plaintext. Your above suggestion return result as empty